# Regex to match everything to a blank line

Tags: java, regex

I've tried for hours and I'm sure I'm missing something simple.
I'm trying to create a method in Java that takes some text and extracts a part of it.

I'd like to match everything from 'Notes' to the first blank line after this

Example input

```
Some info about stuff
Notes: THis is a note about other stuff
So is this
    And this

This is something else
```

The input can be of varying lengths so could also be

```
  BLabla
    Notes: Hello hello
        So is this
            And this
    And this too
    also

 Now I have something else to say
```

Needed output:
Example 1

```
Notes: THis is a note about stuff
So is this
    And this
```

Example 2

```
 Notes: Hello hello
        So is this
            And this
    And this too
    also
```

I've tried:

```
public static String NotesExtractor(String str){
        String mynotes=null;
        str=str+"\n\n"+"ENDOFLINE";
        Pattern Notesmatch_pattern = Pattern.compile("Notes:(.*?)^\\s*$",Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher Notesmatchermatch_pattern = Notesmatch_pattern.matcher(str);
        if (Notesmatchermatch_pattern.find()) {     
        String h = Notesmatchermatch_pattern.group(1).trim();
        mynotes=h;

    }
        mynotes=mynotes.replaceAll("^\\n", "").trim();
        return mynotes;

    }
```

but I don't get any matches and I'm not sure why.

Comment: If you do with `replaceAll`, target the part before `Notes:` and after two newlines. Try pattern string: `"(?s)^.*?(?=Notes:)|(?:\\r?\\n){2}.*"`. You can use `DOTALL` instead of `(?s)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
(?s)Notes.*?(?=\n\n)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC6aZ8/1)**

*Java Code*

```
String line = "Some info about stuff\nNotes: THis is a note about other stuff\nSo is this\n    And this\n\nThis is something else"; 
String pattern = "(?s)Notes.*?(?=\n\n|$)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/32DVOp)**

Comment: The input can be of varying length so really need a way of matching the first black line with inputs of varying length. So I guess I need to use Patter.DOTALL.  I have altered my question to clarify this.

Comment: @SebastianZeki you can take input from user..i don't understand what you are implying

Comment: My apologies. It does work fine. I still can't get the output I want but it's clearly not a regex problem so given the regex is correct points awarded

Comment: @SebastianZeki yeah..maybe you need to recheck your code then